# ASP.NET Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown with GridView control

Tags: asp.net, gridview, out-of-memory

My datatable has more then 1000000 records.
After binding it to GridView Datasourse, my page shows

> System.OutOfMemoryException

What is the approach and if there are any examples of how to code it, to take top 1000 records from that datatable and bind it to GridView.

That is the fragment of my code:

```
DataTable dt = GetReport(dateFrom, dateTo);

ViewState[_vsReport] = dt;
gvReport.DataSource = dt;
gvReport.DataBind();
```

Comment: Search for grid view paging. And also don't put it in view state, that's not what view state is for

Comment: The think is that before even be able to page throw `GridView`, I need to load the data into the `GridView`, but it is not loading because of the `Exception`

Comment: Comment still holds, look up how paging is done. It should be done _before_ you load data into gridview